# npm outdated command shows MISSING in current version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I have babelify in version 7.3.0 specified in devDependencies in my package.json file like below:

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...,
  "babelify": "7.3.0",
  ...
}
```

Everything is going fine and the dependency is downloaded from npm but when I've run `npm outdated` command I've got:

```
Package       Current  Wanted        Latest  Location
babelify      MISSING   7.3.0         7.3.0  project
```

What is going on here? Why MISSING? Did you have such situation?

Comment: When you `cd` to your project directory and run `$ npm list babelify` does it report `(empty)` ?

Comment: Nope. I have something like: +-- babelify@7.3.0  extraneous
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY watchify@>=3 <4

npm ERR! peer dep missing: watchify@>=3 <4, required by karma-browserify-intellij@5.1.1
npm ERR! extraneous: babelify@7.3.0

Comment: Very odd!  It also seems strange that `devDependencies` doesn't report `"babelify": "^7.3.0"` _(I.e. There is no [Caret](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) symbol)_. You could try deleting the `node_modules` folder, adding the caret in `package.json` and running `$ npm install` again.

Comment: Nope. Still same issue.

Comment: Had the same issue, nothing would fix it except for 'npm update' (deleting node_modules and running npm install would not resolve it).

Answer (score 3):

Weird thing guys. After a while I noticed that I have a space after word babelify and the quotation mark. So I had:

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...,
  "babelify ": "7.3.0",
  ...
}
```

instead of:

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...,
  "babelify": "7.3.0",
  ...
}
```

When I removed the space everything is OK.

Comment: I had the exact same error with the exact same result! Thank god for StackOverflow. So apparently the 'npm outdated' command does not trim the package name, while all the other tools does.

Answer (score 2):

> What is going on here? Why MISSING? Did you have such situation?

MISSING means that package is not installed.

Installing the package will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you must install all the packages using `npm install`.
Then `npm outdated` will display current installed version.

Answer (score 0):

missing mean, that you doesnt install the dependency in node_module but you write manually in package.json.